# Why is perl special variable @+ 1-index based when @- is 0-index based?

Tags: perl, indexing

It seems to me that this will cause chaos unless one remembers the need to perform different operations when looking up the start/end positions of substrings versus characters.

In the code shared by user966588reports $-[0] holds value 10 as the index of the start of Hello, while $+[0] holds 15 as the index of the end, when in reality that index is 14.

Comment: *"In the code shared by user966588"* - if you want to refer to another question the please link to it. Otherwise it would be unclear what this phrase refers to. Apart from that the behavior is consistent with other behavior in perl - it is the same as `pos` does and also `$-[1] + length($1) = $+[1]` etc

Comment: From perlvar(1): "$+[1] is the offset **past** where $1 ends". Effectively, `$+[1]` == `$-[2]`

Comment: @jhnc, Re "*Effectively, `$+[1]` == `$-[2]`*", In general, this is wrong. There can be a gap between captures (`/(.).(.)/`). Lookarounds could even make it so `$+[1]` is larger than `$-[2]` (`/(?=(.))(.)/`)

Comment: @ikegami good point

Answer (score 4):

Both arrays are 0-based. I don't know what problem you are seeing or where you read that information, but it's not right.

- `$-[0]`, the first item in the array `@-`, is the index for the starting position for the entire match. Think of this as the position of the start of `$&`.
- `$+[0]`, the first item in the array `@+`, is the index for the ending position for the entire match. Think of this as the position of the end of `$&`. I remember this that "+" has more than "-", so `@+` has the ending positions.
- After that, the indices in those array are the number of the capture buffer they represent.
- The ending positions are the regex cursor position, so after you have matched a character, that cursor advances one. This is the position where the next part of the match starts. From the docs:

> This is the same value as what the pos function returns when called on the variable that was matched against.

Maybe you saw something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.26;

"1234567890" =~ m/(456)\d/;

say <<~"HERE";
    \$1 is  $1
        starts: $-[1]
        end:    $+[1]
    \$&:    $&
        starts: $-[0]
        ends:   $+[0]
    HERE
```

The output:

```
$1 is  456
    starts: 3
    end:    6
$&:    4567
    starts: 3
    ends:   7
```

The start of the capture buffer `$1` is at position 3, and that's the same as the start over the portion of the string matched. However, the capture ends at position 6 (which is the seventh position because we are zero-based), but the overall match kept going to match one more digit. It's ending position is one past the end of the first capture buffer, so it's ending offset is also one greater.

Now the trick is to figure out why having the ending position one past the position of the last character is helpful. Remember that `substr` takes a starting position and a length. I find that very annoying because I usually know the ending position and not the length, but that's life. However, substracting the corresponding values in `@+` and `@-` gives the right length:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.26;

my $string = '1234567890';
$string =~ m/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/;

my $n = int(rand 5);
printf "capture <%s> was <%s>\n", $n, substr $string, $-[$n], $+[$n] - $-[$n];
```

And some runs (remember capture 0 is the part of the string that matched the entire pattern):

```
$ perl test.pl
capture <1> was <12>
$ perl test.pl
capture <3> was <56>
$ perl test.pl
capture <0> was <1234567890>
$ perl test.pl
capture <4> was <78>
$ perl test.pl
capture <3> was <56>
$ perl test.pl
capture <1> was <12>
$ perl test.pl
capture <0> was <1234567890>
$ perl test.pl
capture <1> was <12>
```

Comment: The code above perfectly illustrates my point: with a search for "456" within "1234567890," $-[0] reports "3" as the index of the start of the match (this is using a 0-based index); $+[0] reports "6" as the index of the end of the match (this is using a 1-based index).

Comment: It's not a 1-based index. Read my answer again.